# How can I make it so I am able to call the function with a certain stock,

Tags: python

```
def live_price(stock):
    string = (data.decode("utf-8"))
    conn.request("GET", f"/stock/{stock}/ohlc", headers=headers)
    print(Price)
live_price("QCOM")
```

I want to be able to type "live_price("stockname") and then have the function output the data for the stock. If anyone can help that would be great. All other variables mentioned are defined elsewhere in the code.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of the code. What is your data source? yfinance? Please try to be slightly more comprehensive when asking a question. Let me know, I will be glad to help.

Comment: res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

def live_price(stock):
    string = (data.decode("utf-8"))
    conn.request("GET", f"/stock/{stock}/ohlc", headers=headers)
    string_split = string.split(':')
    data_v = {i: string_split[i] for i in range(0, len(string_split))}
    data_v2 = data_v[2].split(',')
    dataV3 = {i: data_v2[i] for i in range(0, len(data_v2))}
    Price = float(dataV3[0])
    print(Price)
live_price("QCOM")

Answer (score 0):

```
import yfinance

def live_price(stock):
    inst = yfinance.download(stock)
    print(inst['Open'][-1])
```

When one has a hammer, everything looks like a nail. Or, in different words - The best solution for your problem will actually be achieved with Google Sheets as it has access to Google Finance live data (which is by far the best possible data source for live prices). If you'd later like to make any analysis using Python, you can just draw data from your google sheet either locally with your preferred code editor, or even better, while using Google Colabratory.